# upload backup file thru webAPI

Tags: httpclient

I try to upload setup backup file from one AGV into another. So that I do not have to setup again in another AGV. I did it in postman successfuly. But I do not know why it can not be done in C#.

```
public static async Task UploadSite(string url, string accessToken, string filePath)
{
    using (var httpClient = new HttpClient())
    {
        using (var formData = new MultipartFormDataContent())
        {
            httpClient.DefaultRequestHeaders.Authorization = 
                new AuthenticationHeaderValue("Bearer", accessToken);

            formData.Add(new StringContent("db_backup_archive_file"));

            byte[] fileBytes = File.ReadAllBytes(filePath);
            var fileContent = new ByteArrayContent(fileBytes);
            formData.Add(fileContent, "file", Path.GetFileName(filePath));

            HttpResponseMessage response = await httpClient.PostAsync(url, formData);
            if (response.IsSuccessStatusCode)
            {
                Console.WriteLine("File uploaded successfully.");
            }
            else
            {
                Console.WriteLine($"Failed to upload file. Status code: {response}");
            }
        }
    }
}
```

The postman screen is like this.
[image]

program running result is like this

```
Failed to upload file. Status code: StatusCode: 400, ReasonPhrase: 'BAD REQUEST', 
        Version: 1.0, Content: System.Net.Http.StreamContent, Headers:
{
  Access-Control-Allow-Origin: *
  Date: Fri, 11 Aug 2023 07:44:15 GMT
  Server: Werkzeug/1.0.0
  Server: Python/3.8.10
  Content-Length: 98
  Content-Type: application/json
}
```

Can someone help me what's wrong for formData in my program?